# How to reinitialize model when client side validation fails in Yii 2?

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, model, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on Yii 2 form and I want to reinitialize model when client side validation fails. For example with certain rules like below:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username'], 'required', 'message' => 'You must enter your username'],
        ['username','email'],
        [['password'], 'required', 'message' => 'You must enter your password'],           
    ];
}
```

When validation fails I want all fields to be empty (for example when user enters invalid email address). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use standard Yii 2 way of loading the model:

```
$model = new SomeModel();
if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    // ...
}
return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
```

Set fields to `null` when validation fails. You don't want to create new instance (which would be easier) because you would lost all validation messages.

```
$model = new SomeModel();
if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    if ($model->save()) {
        // ....
    } else {
        $model->username = null;
        $model->password = null;
    }
}
return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
```

UPDATE: for the client side validation add this JS code in view:

```
$("#form-ID").on("afterValidateAttribute", function (event, attribute, messages) {
    if (event.result === false) {
        attribute.value = "";
    }
});
```

Replace `#form-ID` with proper form element JS identifier.

Comment: yes i am already do like that, but this is after posting so page will refresh thats why i am ask if any possible way to without page refresh

Comment: i am using afterValidate instead of afterValidateAttribute,it's working fine and it's give another idea to me,thank u so much